# How do I sync my RunKeeper workout schedule with Google Calender?

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization, runkeeper

I have a RunKeeper account with an Elite subscription. I joined a training plan and can see the workout schedule on the website. I would like to sync this schedule with my Google calendar.

- I tried [exporting my data](http://support.runkeeper.com/entries/21696773-How-to-Export-your-RunKeeper-data) for the duration of the workout, but the schedule wasn't exported with it
- I linked my RunKeeper account with the app [Run Calendar](http://runkeeper.com/apps/run-calendar/43559) app which boasts "Export activities to Google/iCal and Excel" but I couldn't find a way to link/export my workout schedule.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a ["If This Then That" recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/110721-runkeeper-to-gcal) you could utilize.

> **Notes:** Uses http://iamnerdwin.com/work/runkeeper-activity-feed to
>   export data from RunKeeper and then http://www.feed43.com to turn the
>   data into RSS. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqnfG.jpg for key settings in
>   feed43.

It shouldn't require much tweaking at all. Just an IFTTT.com account (they're free!).

Comment: Feed43 is down for the moment but this seems promising! I just signed up for a sub 4-hour marathon plan so I'm looking forward to test this out to see if this works.

Comment: https://ifttt.com/ is a wonderful site. SO FAR they are free, too. So go them.